# Синтаксис не читается pdo php

Tags: php, pdo

Код выдает ошибку в строке 10:

```html
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '****';
    $user = '***';
    $pass = '***';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Z:\home\localhost\www\Work_Log\db.php on line 10

непонятно, мб проблемы с версиями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо обновить версию РНР.

Синтаксис квадратных скобок для массивов появился в версии 5.4. Это значит, что ваша версия РНР устарела **более 10 лет назад**. Текущей версией является РНР 7.3.

В качестве временного решения можно заменить квадратные скобки `[]` на `array()`

Answer (score -3):

уберите запятую после

```
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
```